# R - Installing package "xlsx"

Tags: r, xlsx, rjava

I'm trying to install the package "xlsx" in RStudio. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I am new to programming. I uses the code

```
install.packages("xlsx")
```

While the installation process I got warnings:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 6
warning: [options] source value 6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
```

After that some things are not found:

```
/usr/bin/ld: -lpcre2-8 kann nicht gefunden werden
/usr/bin/ld: -llzma kann nicht gefunden werden
/usr/bin/ld: -lbz2 kann nicht gefunden werden
/usr/bin/ld: -lz kann nicht gefunden werden
```

And the installation process stopps.

The whole code is here:

```
install.packages("xlsx")
Installiere Paket nach ‘/home/carla/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(da ‘lib’ nicht spezifiziert)
installiere auch Abhängigkeiten ‘rJava’, ‘xlsxjars’

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rJava_1.0-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1047062 bytes (1022 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1022 KB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/xlsxjars_0.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 9477071 bytes (9.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 9.0 MB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/xlsx_0.6.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 489493 bytes (478 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 478 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
configure: checking whether gcc supports static inline...
yes
checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac'
header prep.: ''
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... yes
checking whether -Xrs is supported... yes
checking whether -Xrs will be used... yes
checking whether JVM will be loaded dynamically... no
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking whether JNI programs run... yes
checking JNI data types... ok
checking whether JRI should be compiled (autodetect)... yes
checking whether debugging output should be enabled... no
checking whether memory profiling is desired... no
checking whether threads support is requested... no
checking whether callbacks support is requested... no
checking whether JNI cache support is requested... no
checking whether headless init is enabled... no
checking whether JRI is requested... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating R/zzz.R
config.status: creating src/config.h
=== configuring in jri (/tmp/Rtmpbi2fIb/R.INSTALLaa4513637492/rJava/jri)
configure: running /bin/bash ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking Java version... 11.0.14.1
checking Java compatibility version (integer)... 11
checking whether  actually works... no
checking whether javah was replaced by javac -h... yes
checking for target flags...  -h . -target 1.6 -source 1.6
checking whether Java interpreter works... checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking whether JNI programs can be run... yes
checking JNI data types... ok
checking whether Rinterface.h exports R_CStackXXX variables... yes
checking whether Rinterface.h exports R_SignalHandlers... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating run
config.status: creating src/config.h
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Rglue.c -o Rglue.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c arrayc.c -o arrayc.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c callJNI.c -o callJNI.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c callback.c -o callback.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fields.c -o fields.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c jri_glue.c -o jri_glue.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c loader.c -o loader.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c otables.c -o otables.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rJava.c -o rJava.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c registration.c -o registration.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c tools.c -o tools.o
gcc -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o rJava.so Rglue.o arrayc.o callJNI.o callback.o fields.o init.o jri_glue.o loader.o otables.o rJava.o registration.o tools.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
(cd ../jri && make)
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/tmp/Rtmpbi2fIb/R.INSTALLaa4513637492/rJava/jri“ wird betreten
make -C src JRI.jar
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/tmp/Rtmpbi2fIb/R.INSTALLaa4513637492/rJava/jri/src“ wird betreten
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac -h . -target 1.6 -source 1.6  -d . ../package-info.java ../RFactor.java ../REXP.java ../Rengine.java ../RList.java ../Mutex.java ../RConsoleOutputStream.java ../RMainLoopCallbacks.java ../RVector.java ../RBool.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 6
warning: [options] source value 6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 warnings
if [ -n "" ]; then  -d . -classpath . org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine; fi
gcc -c -o Rengine.o Rengine.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include 
gcc -c -o jri.o jri.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include 
gcc -c -o Rcallbacks.o Rcallbacks.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include 
gcc -c -o Rinit.o Rinit.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include 
gcc -c -o globals.o globals.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux 
gcc -c -o rjava.o rjava.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux 
gcc -o libjri.so Rengine.o jri.o Rcallbacks.o Rinit.o globals.o rjava.o  -shared -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre2-8 -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm -licuuc -licui18n 
/usr/bin/ld: -lpcre2-8 kann nicht gefunden werden
/usr/bin/ld: -llzma kann nicht gefunden werden
/usr/bin/ld: -lbz2 kann nicht gefunden werden
/usr/bin/ld: -lz kann nicht gefunden werden
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/tmp/Rtmpbi2fIb/R.INSTALLaa4513637492/rJava/jri/src“ wird verlassen
make[2]: *** [Makefile.all:37: libjri.so] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile.all:19: src/JRI.jar] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/tmp/Rtmpbi2fIb/R.INSTALLaa4513637492/rJava/jri“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makevars:14: jri] Fehler 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/carla/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘xlsxjars’
* removing ‘/home/carla/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/xlsxjars’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xlsxjars’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘rJava’, ‘xlsxjars’ are not available for package ‘xlsx’
* removing ‘/home/carla/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/xlsx’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xlsx’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpYSDmLA/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried to first install "rJava" but there were also the same warnings and it stopped at the same part.

And now I don't know what to do, maybe some of you can help me?

Comment: I have a had similar experience with this package. If possible, I would switch to a package that does not require Java, like `openxlsx`, which allows you to do all the same things without the added complication of maintaining a Java installation.

Comment: Looks like `ld` can't be found. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils`